# Error sending saved audio via whatsapp (Android studio)

Tags: android, audio, whatsapp

The code I'm using is this:

```
String path= "android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+R.raw.a1;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent compartiraudio = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
compartiraudio.setType("audio/*");
compartiraudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartiraudio, "Comparte un archivo de audio"));
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong but after opening the share menu and accepting, it gives me an error.

Comment: Please post the details of your error (the full traceback if possible).

Comment: The share menu shows up. You select whatsapp, then you select the conversation where you want to send it and after opening this is what happens:
https://gyazo.com/d98801c221c11cbcbe7457ae91561905
"Sharing Failed. Please, try it again."

Comment: This is what the console shows/says:
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa15d7e90
E/EGL_emulation: tid 5178: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)